# Getting error when compiling with Laravel Mix Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack

I'm trying simple to-do in laravel vue.
This is my code from ./resources/js/app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

import Vue from 'vue'

import App from './vue/app'

const chatapp = new Vue({
    el: '#chatdiv',
    components: { App }
});
```

I have created vue folder in ./resources/js and added app.vue file in that.

Now when I try to run 'npm run development' it gives me following error

```
> @ development D:\test\laravue
> mix

i Compiling Mix
ΓêÜ Mix: Compiled with some errors in 9.45s
ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js 4:0-27
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue/app' in 'D:\test\laravue\resources\js'

webpack compiled with 1 error
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-25T13_46_36_740Z-debug.log
```

My package.json file contains this

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^2.6.12"
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to resolve this error? Thank you.

Comment: This directory doesn't exists, or it is given wrong `'vue/app'` please check that part

Comment: Yes. My mistake. Its './vue/app'. Edited the question. That /app for app.vue file in vue folder.

Answer (score 0):

`Vue` doesnt have `app` folder in it, you can't import `App from ./vue/app` because vue doesn't have `app`.

You can create `App.vue` near your `app.js`, then in `app.js` you can import it
`import App from ./App`

Your `App.vue` can be like:

```
<template>
    <div>Hello from App!</div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
      name: "App"
    }

</script>
```